# Send activation code by email after registration instead of URL

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt, djoser

As we seen in different websites, After user's sign-up it sends an activation code with 6/5 character to user's email. User should submit the code in the website to activate their account.
I am trying to do the same thing but can't figure it out how to do it in django-rest-framework using djoser.

Currently, I am using Djoser for registration and activation. Djoser sends activation URL in the email; which activates the account when clicked on and It's working fine.

How can I can send a 6 character alphanumeric code for activation to the user, instead of sending the whole URL?

I'm using:
django-rest-framework,
django-rest-framework-jwt,
djoser

Answer (score 2):

I've used a variation of the following in projects:

```
# models.py
import random

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


def generate_activation_code():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(6))


class ActivationCode(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=generate_activation_code)


# views.py
from django.http import Http404

def register_user(request):
    # create your `new_user` however you see fit
    code = ActivationCode.objects.create(user=new_user)
    send_mail(
        'Activate Your Account',
        'Here is the activation code: %s' % code,
        'from@example.com',
        [user.email]
    )
    render(request, 'activation_sent.html')

def check_activation_code(request, code):
    try:
        ActivationCode.objects.get(code=code)
        # ... All set, activate & login the user, & delete the activation code
    except ActivationCode.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return render(request, 'welcome.html')
```

Enhancements could include adding an expiry date to the `ActivationCode` that you check in the view, and/or a management job to clean old codes.

Comment: How we can integrate this solution into djoser email confirmation system? I'm asking because the djoser library has implemented a method to send verification urls directly to user's email without needing any programming (it should only be activated in settings.py). How to force djoser to generate this code model automatically and send it instead of an url? Please expand your code to adapt this system. Thank you.

Comment: I've never used DJoser, but it looks like it sends an email with an activation link the user clicks to make the process as transparent as possible. If I'm understanding what you want, I don't think you can do this without bypassing a lot of the DJoser functionality. You may be able to replace the token generation it does by updating the `TOKEN_MODEL` setting and overriding the `ActivationEmail` to use your own, but I think it's still going to be a link the user clicks and is logged in.

Comment: It sounds like you want to have a sort of "confirmation" page that the user enters the six character code into. If that's the case, I think you'd be better off without Djoser, based on what you've described. I've added a bit more detail about how I'd approach it without Djoser.

Comment: I'm designing an app with DRF and user will enter the code into my app; then a request will be sent to some endpoint and Django will verify if the code is valid. I think It should be possible to tinker some of djoser's functionality and make this feature available; but it's not going to be easy. If there comes no better solution, I will award the bounty. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a random value, encode some unique user data and append it to the url. like this

```
import jwt
data = {'email' : "test@test.com"} # Some unique field for reference
secret_key = "test"
algorithm = "HS256" # You can use MD5 or whatever you want
jwt.encode(data, secret_key, algorithm)
```

After they click the mail activation url you can decode and validate the unique field in Database. For this you don't want save the code in DB. It's my suggestion

Comment: ....thank you ..but thing is that it will generate too long code...its not easy for a user to write this long code at the time of activation ...how to generate short code between 5 to 8 character

Comment: You didn't get my point, i just give sample code either you can use this orelse you can send some unique value that will identify the user (i.e user id or table row id) anything. that's your wish. Because , after they click the link in mail you need to do some validation.

Comment: If the solution is resolved your issues, you need to accept and upvote. It will be useful other peoples who will face the same issues.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate 6 digit random number:

```
import random  
codeval = random.randint(111111,999999)
```

And send it with email. And you can keep exact the same copy of the random number. And when user will give his number. You can match it with the stored one. If it matches then you will activate the user profile.

Comment: thanks...is there any way other than storing the code...like signing with key or some like